# Wordpress personalized permalink

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

Bonjour!

I'm using a translation plugin on my web site that doesn't display on mobile display (column where the plugin is displayed is not visible on mobile).

When I put my article in english, the url becomes:

```
frenchyincali.com/my-article/**?lang=en**
```

Thus, I'd like to include a link in my code that is very basic: Getting the permalink and add the suffix "**?lang=en**" for the english link and just the default permalink for the default language (French).

I guess it'd be something like `<?php the_permalink();>`... But then I don't know what to put to add the suffix. Can you help me please?

I tried to find something elsewhere but I can't find the answer; Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Displays the URL for the permalink to the post currently being processed in The Loop.

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>?lang=en">English Article</a>
```

Comment: Hi, I've tested the code and I have the first part of the answer. Now, when the article is in English, is it possible to take the permalink and remove the "?lang=en" to go back in the original language? Thanks!

Comment: EDIT: I've used the same kind of link you told me to use but added "?lang=fr" for the default version. It is working but if you have a solution without this suffix it could be awesome! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Add functions.php

```
function lang() {
$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
    if($lang == "en") {
        $suffix = "?lang=en";
    } elseif($lang == "tr") {
        $suffix = "?lang=tr";
    } else {
        $suffix = "";
    }
    return $suffix;
}
```

Use like this:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?><?php echo lang(); ?>">Article</a>
```

I think this way is simple.

Comment: I don't understand your code, I pasted it but it doesn't work it's just displaying "article" and nothing is changing.... Can you help me more?